# OpenFient Leaderboard Custom UI iPhone

Tags: iphone, openfeint, leaderboard

I am using OpenFient for an online leaderboard in my game, but how can I get the leader board data (say top ten)? then display it in my own custom UI? Rather than having to use the open feint screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the the sample code included in the OF SDK for code demonstrating how to do this for either iOS or Android.

The following article provides an overview relevant to the iOS implementation:
http://support.openfeint.com/dev/leaderboards/